# pyinstaller package of pyqgis 3 standalone program failed import qgis.core

Tags: pyqgis-3, qgis-3, pyinstaller

I have a working standalone pyqgis program with mapping ability, it was in python 2.7 and qgis 2.x library. I used pyinstaller to package it up. Now I have migrated this application to python 3.6 and qgis 3.2.1-Bonn and pyqt 5.9. It is working fine in the PyCharm environment, the map is working, basically, qgis imports are working, such as:

```
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsVectorLayer
```

I tried to package it up with pyinstaller 3.3.1 (as I have done successfully for the python 2.7 version of the program), it can get all of the qgis pyd/dlls into the package and the Qt GUI is running, it just keeps failing the qgis import statements such as above. The whole package is gathered into the C:\dist\qgis_test\ folder that contains the following qgis libs:

```
qgis._core.pyd
qgis._gui.pyd
qgis_core.dll
qgis_gui.dll
qgis_native.dll
```

When running the packaged executable file, it always bombs at the point of importing modules from the qgis.core or qgis.gui packages as shown below:

```
PYIMOD03: fullname=qgis._gui
PYIMOD03: filename=C:\dist\qgis_test\qgis._gui.pyd
PYIMOD03: fullname=qgis._core
PYIMOD03: filename=C:\dist\qgis_test\qgis._core.pyd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "qgis_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsVectorLayer, QgsProject
  File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "qgis\core\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 716, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

The thing is that all of the PyQt5 libraries are all imported without error.

I've already set the following environmental variables to the package root directory (because that's where qgis_core.dll and qgis_gui.dll are located) like I did for the python 2 package:

```
QGIS, QGIS_PREFIX_PATH, PATH, PYTHONPATH, QT_PLUGIN_PATH
```

I pretty much searched and read up all python3 qgis related threads here and via google, but not much information is out there. Also, I noticed that the Qt plugins are under PyQt5\Qt\plugins within the package directory, I also set the environment variables accordingly to that, but still no luck. It keeps failing on those qgis import statements.